# Manually post to an Asp.Net MVC controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, controller

I have a controller that looks like this for importing xml to my site:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Import(string xml)
    {
```

I have a standalone application that reads an xml file and sends it to the url. It looks like this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var reader = new StreamReader(@"myfile.xml");
        var request = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:41379/mycontroller/import");
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "text/xml";
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream());
        sw.Write(reader.ReadToEnd());
        sw.Close();
        var theResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(theResponse.GetResponseStream());
        var response = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }
```

The controller gets called properly, but when I break in there, the argument is null. I am pretty sure I am just not setting the right content type or something like that. What is the proper way to encode the xml so that the framework will get it and give it to the controller properly?

Comment: Where are you passing the xml content to the action?

Comment: I am writing it to the request stream.

Comment: but you are not giving it a name.  It needs to be a formal named HTTP POST param.

Comment: you are also missing a lot of using statements there for your streams and requests

Comment: @crice, yes, but that is the entire program, so they'll get disposed anyway. @kirk, thats kinda what I'm asking how to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>Save yourself a lot of grief and use [WebClient.UploadFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36s52zhs.aspx).</strike>

Having led you the wrong way, I wrote a controller and client that seem to work fine:

**Controller**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Upload()
    {
        XDocument doc;
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream))
        {
            doc = XDocument.Load(sr);
        }
        return Content(doc.ToString());
    }
}
```

**client**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://host/Home/Upload");
    req.Method = "POST";
    req.ContentType = "text/xml";

    using (var stream = File.OpenRead("myfile.xml"))
    using (var requestStream = req.GetRequestStream()) {
        stream.CopyTo(requestStream);
    }


    using (var response = (HttpWebResponse) req.GetResponse())
    using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
    using (var sr = new StreamReader(responseStream))
    {
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(sr);
        Console.WriteLine(doc);
    }


    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: good point. I can just read the input stream. I don't really need the framework to parse it out for me at all. I'll try this soon.